# Covariant derivative of $(0,0)$-tensor calculation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

I am trying to prove a special case of proposition 4.21 in "Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds" by John Lee. Here is the setup: $\nabla$ is a connection in $TM$, $f\in C^\infty(M)$ (ie a $(0,0)$-type tensor) and $X,Y$ are smooth vector fields. I am trying to prove that $\nabla^2_{X,Y} f=\nabla_X(\nabla_Y f)-\nabla_{\nabla_X Y} f$. Here, for any $(k,l)$-tensor $F$, we define $\nabla^2_{X,Y} F=\nabla^2 F(\dots, Y,X)$.

Here is what I have done:

\begin{align*}
\nabla^2_{X,Y} f&=\nabla(\nabla (f) (Y,X))\\&=\nabla(X(f(Y))-f(\nabla_X Y))\\&
=\nabla(X(f(Y)))-\nabla(f(\nabla_X Y))\\&
=\nabla_Y(Xf)-\nabla_{\nabla_X Y}f\\&=\nabla_Y(\nabla_X f)-\nabla_{\nabla_X Y}f.
\end{align*}
But this is very clearly not quite what I want...The $X$ and $Y$ seem to have switched places in the first term and I don't know where I went wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\nabla^2 f) (X,Y)=\nabla (\nabla f)(X,Y)=\nabla_X (\nabla f) (Y)$.

Let $T:=\nabla f$ for clarity.

Now, we continue the computation (using $\nabla f(X)=X(f)$):

$\nabla_X T (Y)=X(T(Y))-T(\nabla_X Y)=X(Y(f))-\nabla_X Y(f)$

Finally, we obtain what you want by $\nabla_X f=\nabla f(X)=X(f)$.

The problem is that you "worked" from the inside instead that from the outside.

Comment: Right! Thank you very much. I see the problem with what I was doing...I should have been treating $\nabla f$ as a tensor so that $\nabla f (Y)$ is a function over $M$ and therefore, $X(\nabla f (Y))=\nabla_X (\nabla f(Y))$