# What does this notation regarding covariant differentiation mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, connections

Suppose we are considering the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ on a Riemannian manifold $M$. By definition, $\nabla$ is a map
$$\nabla:\Gamma(TM)\to\Gamma(TM^*\otimes TM)$$
satisfying certain conditions. If $X,Y$ are vector fields on $M$, I can understand that $\nabla Y\in\Gamma(TM^*\otimes TM)$, and $\nabla_XY\in\Gamma(TM)$.

However, I've seen $\nabla$ used in the following way: Let $\xi^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ be a tangent vector field. Then $\sum_{j}\nabla_j\xi^j$ equals the divergence of $\xi^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350574/why-is-the-divergence-theorem-used-in-the-eells-sampson-paper-slightly-different).

**Questions:**

1. What does it mean to write $\nabla_j\xi^j$? $\xi^j$ itself is not a tensor, but a component of a tensor. But by definition, the input of $\nabla_j$ should be a tensor. Is it a shorthand or something else?
2. I think using local coordinates, we have $\nabla_if=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ and $\nabla_i\nabla_jf=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}-\Gamma_{ij}^k\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}$. Is this the definition? What about higher derivatives?
3. Even though I am fine with local coordinates, I hope someone can explain this to me in an intrinsic way.

Comment: I can suggest you to read in almost any Riemannian Geometry book (e.g. Do Carmo Riemannian Geometry last pages chapter 4) how to extend the Levi-Civita connection to any tensor (essentially by making the Leibniz rule: $\nabla_X (T\otimes S)=\nabla_X T\otimes S+T\otimes \nabla_X S$) work.

Comment: @F.T. I have read that. But in my question, the input of $\nabla$ is a scalar, not a tensor, which is inconsistent with the definition of $\nabla$ in almost any book. What is it that I misunderstood?  Or is it some convention on the notation? That's what I want to ask about.

Comment: functions are (0,0)-tensors. So, using the formula in Do Carmo, we have $\nabla_X f=X(f)$

Comment: @F.T. Makes sense. But what about the examples in my question? In first example, the comment in that question says $\nabla_j\xi^j$. Now $\xi^j$ is a locally defined function, if what you say is always true, then $\nabla_j\xi^j=\frac{\partial\xi^j}{\partial x^j}$. However, it has been established in that question that this is not the case.

Comment: @F.T. I believe what I am confused about is what does $\nabla_jf$ mean when $f$ is a component of some tensor field. For example, does $\nabla_j\xi^j$ (see the comment above) mean $\nabla_j(\xi^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})$?

Comment: I guess that your confusion lies in the following:

Let's take the total covariant derivative of a function $f$. $\nabla f$ is a (0,1) tensor (i.e. a 1-form) such that $\nabla f(X)=\nabla_X f=X(f)(=df(X))$. If we once again take the total covariant derivative of the tensor $\nabla f$ we get a (0,2) tensor $\nabla \nabla f$ which is usually denoted by $\nabla^2 f$. Now, differently from one expects we have $\nabla^2 f(X,Y)\neq \nabla_X \nabla_Y f=X(Y(f))$. Indeed, $\nabla^2 f(X,Y)$ is precisely what you have written in the right hand side of 2 (which is not correct as it is written).

Comment: you might want to check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537380/covariant-derivative-of-0-0-tensor-calculation/3537815#3537815

Comment: @F.T. Are you saying that $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}$ is actually $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}f$, while $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}-\Gamma^k_{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}$ are the components of the $(0,2)$-tensor $\nabla\nabla f$? This is clearer to me now because your notations are quite well organized. Can you also take a look at question 1? I think it is a little bit different from what you have written here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104569/discussion-between-f-t-and-trisct).

Comment: @F.T. Can you check my reply in the chatroom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $V=V^\mu\partial_\mu$ a vector field, when physicists write something like $\nabla_\mu V^\nu$ they actually mean:
$$\nabla_\mu V^\nu=\partial_\mu V^\nu+V^\rho\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\rho}$$
So this is indeed not just $\nabla_{\partial_\mu}$ applied to the function $V^\nu$. To see what it is, let also $X=X^\mu\partial_\mu$ be a vector field. In coordinates we have:
$$\begin{array}{}
\nabla_X V & =X^\mu\nabla_{\partial_\mu} V \\
&=X^\mu(\nabla_{\partial_\mu} V^\nu)\partial_\nu+X^\mu V^\nu\nabla_{\partial_\mu}\partial_\nu\\
&=X^\mu(\partial_\mu V^\nu)\partial_\nu+X^\mu V^\nu\Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\nu}\partial_\rho \\
&=X^\mu(\nabla_\mu V^\nu)\partial_\nu
\end{array}$$
This means that:
$$\nabla_\mu V^\nu=dx^\nu (\nabla_{\partial_\mu} V)$$
I.e. the $\nabla_\mu V^\nu$ are the coefficients of the map $X\mapsto\nabla_X V$. In particular the quantity you are looking for is the trace of this map:
$$\nabla_\mu V^\mu=Tr(X\mapsto\nabla_X V)$$
(Note that the covariant derivative $\nabla_X V$ is linear in $X$, hence this map is a well defined vector bundle homomorphism, i.e. linear on fibres, and it makes sense to take a trace.)

Comment: Not only in physics, this notation is also commonly used in Riemannian geonetry.

Comment: Ah okay, I've only seen it in my physics courses up till now.